# How do I backup my NEF files as NEF files from my MAC? They automatically convert to JPGs which I don’t want

Tags: raw, backup

I can easily download NEF files from my Nikon D850 to my MacBook and view and edit them within the Photo directory. However, if I try to save them anywhere else, an external hard drive, Google drive, or even another directory on my computer, they automatically get converted to JPGs. I want to backup the NEF files as NEF Files.

Comment: What are you using to save the files? I've never heard of/seen anything like that...

Comment: I don't use a Mac, but files are files. You shouldn't have any trouble copying them bit-for-bit from one hard drive to another. Something fishy is going on.

Comment: Copying is easy, its just that during the copy they are converted to JPG files.

Comment: You should edit your question to add details of your workflow. Why do you *save them*? If you expect your RAW files to be "saved" with the edits you made, then you should export them as JPEG (or any other raster file format). If you need to make a copy/move the original NEF file to another storage location, then you should copy/paste or move the files themselves on your filesystem (via Finder).

Comment: *Copying is easy, its just that during the copy they are converted to JPG files.* - How do you copy them, with what tool? From where to where? There is no reason why a RAW file (NEF or anything else) would be converted *during* a simple file copy.

Answer (score 3):

If by "view and edit them within the Photo directory" you mean you're using the Photos app to open and edit your NEF files, then simply use the **File → Export → Export Unmodified Original...** to copy the NEF files to another drive.

Comment: The File to Export Unmodified says it will save it as an XMP file.  Why nothing seems to save as simply a NEF is beyond me.

Comment: @Matt, the "Export ITPC as XMP" checkbox is just asking if you want the ITPC metadata to also be exported as an XMP sidecar file, since you might have added keywording, etc. in Photos. If you select it and do the export, both the RAW file and an XMP sidecar file are created; if you don't, just the RAW file is made. Just *try* it.

Comment: OK thanks, I see what you are saying, I didn't notice it made two files. This hopefully should solve exporting to a hard drive (which I don't have with me, I'm on the road). I had been mainly trying to upload them to Google drive, etc. and they just convert to jpegs (just an upload "choose file" option, no mention of formatting, etc.). Thanks again.